# Authenticating with SharePoint (NTLM) in iOS app

Tags: ios, sharepoint, authentication, ntlm

I'm having trouble authenticating and getting hold of the auth token when trying to hook up to a Microsoft Share Point service.

Does anyone have a working example for me or some hints as to how to correctly obtain a auth token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Robert Kuzma blog post](http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/making-a-post-in-objective-c-xcode-to-sharepoint-webservice-requiring-windows-ntlm-authenticaton-for-iphone-or-ipad/) about NTLM authentication from iOS to SharePoint. Some additional information on selecting the preferred authentication method can be found [here](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/server-communication/nsurlauthenticationmethodntlm-vs-nsurlauthenticationmethodservertrust).

To summarize, use the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` callback from `NSURLConnection`.

If that doesn't help you, please be specific in what your authentication troubles are.

Answer (score 0):

I found two very important links which are useful to get the solution. The links are:

**1. Using UIWebView**

Here, I only need to pass a URL to `UIWebView`. If the URL is openable, `Office 365` login view will open on your `UIWebView`, where you can enter your login credentials. You can find [the full description with related code at here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571996/Development-of-iPhone-client-application-for-Share).

An other solution is

**2. Creating your own UI for login**

Here, you have to design your own UI and full manual code to authenticate. You can find all the required help related to code, I can say [full code from here](http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2012/12/13/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-in-ios/).